# Restore Missing Objects in SQL Server MASTER Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We had an issue where we were missing Stored Procedures in our SQL 2008 MSDB table - ran the script in the install folder called instmsdb.sql and all objects were back.

Is there a similar script to add all objects back to the MASTER table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) describes how to rebuild all system databases including master; you use the setup program, not a SQL script. But rebuilding the system databases completely recreates them as if you had just installed SQL Server, so the better solution is always to [back up your system databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx).

(I'm assuming that you're on SQL 2008, based on your tags; please always mention the version of SQL Server that you have.)